# How to solve this optimization problem with a limit in it?

Tags: limits, optimization

I am confronted with the following problem:

> minimize w.r.t. $x(T)$: $$\lim_{T\to
>  \infty}\left(x(T)e^{-f(T)}\left(C+A\int^T_0e^{f(t)-at}dt\right)\right)$$
>    subject to the constraint $$\lim_{T\to\infty}\left(e^{-f(T)}x(T)
>  \right)\geq0$$ Where $C, A$ are constants $>0$, $f(t)>0$ except $f(0)=0$.

How would one even begin to solve something like this? I have never solved an equation with a limit like this. We are essentially minimizing with respect to $x(T)$ but with $T=\infty$. Does it even have a solution? Is my problem even well-defined? 
If $A=0$, then the solution clearly becomes: 
$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\left(e^{-f(T)}x(T)
 \right)=0$$

While I understand that this has to be the solution (setting it to zero is the minimal value it can take without violating the constraint), I don't really understand how it is derived formally, especially when $A\neq0$.

How do we solve this/make sense of this?

Comment: "minimize wrt. $x(T)$" could be written better, because $T$ is already a local variable in the limit.
if you mean to minimize over a function $x:[0,\infty)\to (-\infty,\infty)$, please specify a function space

Comment: @supinf To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how to think of this. $x(t)$ is a  differentiable function, but we only adjust the value of $x(t)$ at $t=T$, where $T\to \infty$. So we're only maximizing with respect to one variable, not w.r.t. a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal value is always $0$.
For each feasible $x$ we have
 $$\lim_{T\to
 \infty}\left(x(T)e^{-f(T)}\left(C+A\int^T_0e^{f(t)-at}dt\right)\right)
 \geq 
 C\lim_{T\to\infty}\left(e^{-f(T)}x(T)
 \right)\geq0
 $$
 even if $A>0$.

If you choose $x(t)=0$ for all $t$, then the function value is $0$ and therefore $x$ is an optimal solution.
On the other hand, this problem does not have a unique solution.
Depending of $f(t)$, even negative values for $x$ are allowed,
for example if $f=0$ then $x(t)=-e^{-t}$ is still an optimal solution.

**Edit 1**:
If you make the additional assumption that $f(t)=\alpha t$ with $\alpha>0,\alpha<a$,
then the integral in the objective function is bounded.
In this case a solution $x$ is characterized by the condition

$$ \lim_{T\to\infty}\left(e^{-\alpha T}x(T)\right)=0.  $$

In particular, some exponential growth for $x$ is still possible.

In the case of $f(t)=\alpha t$,$\alpha>0,a$
the integral is not bounded, but grows as $e^{(\alpha-a)t}$.
In this case a solution can be characterized by the condition

$$ \lim_{T\to\infty}\left(e^{-a T}x(T)\right)=0.  $$

The remaining case is $f(t)=\alpha t$ where $\alpha=a>0$.
In this case the solution is characterized by
$$ \lim_{T\to\infty}\left(T e^{-a T}x(T)\right)=0.  $$

Comment: "If you choose $x(t)=0$ for all $t$". But the thing is, we are only optimizing with respect to $x(T)$ as $T\to \infty$.  The result should be some condition $\lim_{T\to\infty}(x(T)....)=...$, because we don't want to rule out functions $x(t)$ that behave in many different ways with finite $t$, rather than being 0 everywhere. I.e. the reault should be a limit condition on $x(T)$ rather than a conatraint on the entiere function $x(t)$

Comment: Also I've added some constraints on f but that really isnt that important.

Comment: the solution is not unique, so i have not ruled out functions that behave differently for finite $t$

Comment: Right, but the problem then is to find a condition on $x(t)$ such that $x(t)$ is a solution if and only if it satisfies that condition.

Comment: That way, you get all solutions at once, rather than guessing a couple of examples of solutions.

Comment: do you have more conditions for $f$ and $a$? because it can be a bit complicated if $f$ grows fast.

Comment: let's say $f(t)=\alpha t, \alpha >0$. This is maybe too simplistic, but I do know that $lim_{t\to\infty} \frac d {dt} f(t) = constant$, so we can approximate that by just saying $f(t)=\alpha t, \alpha >0$.

Comment: edited for that additional assumption

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is some kind of theory that treats these kind of things?

Comment: no, i am not familiar with such a thing